# Are we interested in Winter Bash 2014?

Tags: discussion

Winter Bash is coming up again next month. See 2013's site for more info, in case you haven't heard of this: http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/

Different SE sites can choose to opt in or out. It's fairly harmless; just adds some cosmetic effects (hats) to the site and 'achievements' to earn hats. Before opting in, does anyone have an opinion on whether to enable it for datascience.stackexchange.com or not?

Answer (score 9):

Winter Bash is a very entertaining "competition"! It is really fun to collect those sweet hats :D Given the fact that it is harmless opting in or out, I guess we should indeed opt in. This may as well come out as an opportunity to foment the site with contributions, while also being able to enjoy ourselves. My vote is for having hats!

Comment: OK, I opted in for us.